# What option did I miss when I stashed untracked file in Git, but it didn't restore with git stash pop?

Tags: git, git-stash

I was testing two things at once and had working tree status like:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   component/file.html
    modified:   component/file.scss
    modified:   component/file.ts
    modified:   component2/file.scss

Untracked files:
    common/file.scss
```

I decided to temporarily stash all scss-files to focus on others with `git stash push -m "scss files for later" -- *.scss` So my working tree now looks like this:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   component/file.html
    modified:   component/file.ts
```

Later I popped the same stash back, but the untracked scss (which was *apparently* stashed) file didn't pop:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   component/file.html
    modified:   component/file.scss
    modified:   component/file.ts
    modified:   component2/file.scss
```

As I popped (vs. applied) the stash, the stash ref is now gone.

Should I have applied some sort of flag on pop?
Or was the file gone already when I pushed the stash (meaning: should I have applied some sort of flag *on push*)?

(git version 2.15.0)

---

Steps to reproduce on gist: https://gist.github.com/keinajar/c52d90cded491f82ffbbf5939fc1b044

Referring to gist: if I try to `git stash push -- common/d.scss` instead of `*.scss` I get the error which (based on current answers) would be the expected outcome:

```
error: pathspec 'common/d.scss' did not match any file(s) known to git.
Did you forget to 'git add'?
```

So instead of me missing options, this is a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stash untracked files you need to use `--include-untracked` flag (or `-u`) according to [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash/2.14.0#git-stash-push-p--patch-k--no-keep-index-u--include-untracked-a--all-q--quiet-m--messageltmessagegt--ltpathspecgt82308203) for `push` command.

And about this odd behaviour. Yes, it is a bug. You can find more info in this [mailing list](https://public-inbox.org/git/CA+HNv10i7AvWXjrQjxxy1LNJTmhr7LE4TwxhHUYBiWtmJCOf_A@mail.gmail.com/).

As it says:

> Currently when 'git stash push -- ' is used, untracked files
>   that match the pathspec will be deleted, even though they do not end up
>   in a stash anywhere.

Comment: I added steps to reproduce & output what I get on https://gist.github.com/keinajar/c52d90cded491f82ffbbf5939fc1b044

Comment: So it's a tie: deleting untracked files is a bug, but my mistake was to omit `-u` flag. Thank you for your answer(s) :)

Answer (score 0):

`stash` doesn't affects untracked files. You have done something with it beetwen `push` and `pop`.

Comment: Immediately after the mentioned `git stash` I checked `git status` as I had a hunch stash wouldn't affect untracked files, but status reported the file gone so I assumed it was stashed.